# Circle Progress Bar on Fragment is not showing progress

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-progressbar, event-bus, otto

I'm trying to show feedback the percentage of which they have downloaded data from a server.

The flow goes something like this:

`LoginActivity`
 - onSuccess, call `Service` to download data
 - while `Service` is working, I've already switched the user to `HomeActivity`

`HomeActivity`
  -This activities layout holds a Fragment I created called `LoadingFragment`
  -There is a method in `LoadingFragment` that is `subscribed` to an event that is posted by the `Service`

My problem is that the Fragment UI is not changing at all whenever an event has been posted.

I logged everything, and I can see the event posting the correct data but the data is not being reflected on the UI.

Below is my `Service`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {

    Integer id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    //do sync here
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Make rest call to retrieve all r for id: " + id);
    mRestClient.getApiService().getR(id, new Callback<List<R>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<R> rResponse, Response response) {
            Integer outstanding = routeResponse.size();
            Integer percentage;
            LoadingEvent loadingEvent = new LoadingEvent();
            SyncEvent syncEvent = new SyncEvent();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Callback success r");
            System.out.println("yohellotest");
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Begin insertion");

            DaoMaster daoMaster = MyApp.getDaoMaster();
            DaoSession session = daoMaster.newSession();
            SQLiteDatabase db = session.getDatabase();
            RDao rDao = session.getRDao();
            WDao wDao = session.getWDao();
            JDao jDao = session.getJDao();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--Beginning Transaction--");
            //db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                int counter = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < rResponse.size(); i++) {
                    R r = rResponse.get(i);
                    rDao.insert(r);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inserted r: " + r.getId());

                    for(int j = 0; j < r.getW().size(); j++) {
                        W w = r.getW().get(j);
                        wDao.insert(w);
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inserted w: " + w.getId());

                        for(int k = 0; k < w.getJ().size(); k++) {
                            J j = w.getJ().get(k);
                            jDao.insert(j);
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inserted j: " + j.getJId());
                        }
                    }
                    counter += 1;
                    percentage = (int) Math.floor((double) counter / outstanding * 100);
                    loadingEvent.setPercentage(percentage);
                    bus.post(loadingEvent);

                }
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Finished inserting");
                //db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Exception happened " + e.getMessage().toString());
                System.out.println("yo something happened, but I don't know what");
            } finally {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--Closing transaction--");
                //db.endTransaction();

            }

            syncEvent.setIsSuccess(true);
            syncEvent.setStatus(200);
            bus.post(syncEvent);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Rest call failed for this api");
            System.out.println("failtests");

        }

    });

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

`Fragment` Subscribed Method

```
@Subscribe
public void loadingResponse(final LoadingEvent loadingEvent) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Response from loading: " + loadingEvent.getPercentage());

    if(getActivity() == null)
        return;
    textTest.setText(loadingEvent.getPercentage().toString());
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Updating ui for loading text" + loadingEvent.getPercentage().toString());
            mCircularProgressBar.setProgress(loadingEvent.getPercentage());
            textTest.setText(loadingEvent.getPercentage().toString());
        }
    });

}
```

When I check my Logs, I see everything coming in fine, but the UI is not reflecting it. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention. I'm using this library for my circle progress bar:

[CircleProgressBar](https://github.com/lsjwzh/MaterialLoadingProgressBar)

**EDIT**

As of today, I still have yet to figure this out. I also noticed that my adapter is not being updated when the service posts the event. Previously, the `context` used to `startService()` was the `getApplicationContext()` from the `LoginActivity`. I thought this might have been a problem so I changed it to get the instance of the `HomeActivity` instead. I thought that firing the service from my `HomeActivity` would have solved the problem, but I'm still getting the same results unfortunately.

Comment: Is `textTest` showing the expected value?

Comment: @Roshan the `textTest` is also not showing anything. It remains as the default value that I set it as. `textTest` is a `TextView` for anyone who is curious.

Comment: what about the log in `run` method?

Comment: @Roshan The log in my run method is returning me the integer that I want to show inside the Fragment. So all is working well, just that the UI is not being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so no one really tried to attempt answering my question but I figured it out.

I actually skimped over the documentation part of the `Service` class and didn't know that it was executing on the Main Thread. To fix this, I had to run an `AsyncTask` to execute my operation in the background.

The only thing I had to change in my codebase was to move the executing code from the `onStartCommand` method into an `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` will be initiated `onStartCommand` and everything should be working fine.

My code looks something like this now :

`Service`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LoginEvent> {
     @Override
     protected LoginEvent doInBackground(Void... params) {
          //Code here to run my operations
          //Call api, insert to db, post events etc...
          //
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(LoginEvent event) {
          //run anything here you want to do after execution
     }
}
```

You can ignore my `LoginEvent` as this was something for my event bus to post events to any subscribers.

Also, keep in mind that if you are going to change any views from this `AsyncTask` through the `bus`, make sure the subscriber uses the `runOnUi` to execute or else you'll hit a runtime exception since you're trying to change a view from something other than the `MainThread`.